# Что делать если ошибка RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность

Вот код:

```py
import geometrydash as gd

async def robtopuser():
    user = await gd.search_user("robtop")
    print(user.name)
    print(user.moderator)

robtopuser()
```

`geometrydash` это библиотека для взаимодействия с игрой `Geometry Dash`

(Без await в 4 строчке всё равно та же ошибка)
полная ошибка:

```
C:\Users\matve\Desktop\dgdgdg.py:8: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'robtopuser' was never awaited
  robtopuser()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте информации в вопрос. Совсем не понятно, что такое gd. Скорее всего ошибка в том, что вы забыли использовать ключевое слово await при вызове асинхронной функции gd.search_user("robtop") (опять же, непонятно: асинхронная она или нет). Но все равно попробуйте заменить на user = await gd.search_user("robtop")

Comment: DKay,gd это библиотека для взаимодействия с игрой Geometry Dash. Я уже так пробовал и та же ошибка. Информацию я сейчас добавлю.

Comment: а при вызове robtopuser() вы await забыли.

Comment: Проблема не в корутинах, ошибка вызывается внутри функции `search_user`. Я не особо знаю, что это за либа и игра, но, судя по всему, вы неправильно настроили компьютер/игру/либу (еррор же говорит, что `забыли включить tracemalloc`). Киньте полный листинг ошибки (`и не надо ошибки писать в названии, их крайне неудобно выделять в этом случае`).

Answer (score 1):

У меня была такая же проблема, в функции `main` прописал вот такой код:

```py
asyncio.run(robtopuser())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека `geometrydash` является асинхронной, так что ошибки в функции:

```
async def robtopuser():
    user = await gd.search_user("robtop")
    print(user.name)
    print(user.moderator)
```

нет, всё написано правильно.

Ошибка `RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback` возникает из-за того, что ваша асинхронная функция запускается синхронно:

```
robtopuser()
```

Нужно запустить функцию асинхронно, к примеру используя `asyncio.run()`.

Исправленный код:

```
import geometrydash as gd
import asyncio

async def robtopuser():
    user = await gd.search_user("robtop")
    print(user.name)
    print(user.moderator)

asyncio.run(robtopuser())
```

Также хотел бы подметить, что асинхронные функции не всегда следует запускать используя `asyncio`. К примеру, вы можете запустить асинхронную функцию из другой асинхронной функции используя `await`. Но первая функция должна запускаться используя `asyncio.run()`, или же другим образом используя тот же `asyncio`, прочитайте [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html).